# How to get current KoinApplication instance?

Tags: android, android-studio, dependency-injection, koin, koin-scope

I'm using loadKoinModules to load modules in a multi-module project with Koin  and Jetpack Startup library.

I'm trying this way, but it's an internal function

```
getKoin().createEagerInstances()
```

I have seen that KoinApplication has the createEagerInstances method as public, but I couldn't find a way to get the current KoinApplication instance!

Thanks.

Comment: `createEagerInstances()` gets called when you start koin. What is the issue you're trying to solve at startup?

Comment: I have a multi-module project, and each module has its own set of modules for Koin, I'm using the Jetpack Startup library to load those modules, by allowing them of being independent of the main app module.

Comment: To me jetpack startup is just a way of making ContentProvider-style auto init better. It works when the components are independent. With app-wide dependencies like koin the components are not that independent in that regard. I'd likely rather just pull the koin modules from feature modules manually within the app-level init code that starts koin. The app needs to include all the feature modules anyway, no?

Comment: I chose jetpack startup it's because our app's different modules are developed by different developers, and they don't have access to the app module, so they can't add their module to the startKoin by just modifying the app module, I'm using navigation to include their navigation graph and passing action the graph. that's the way they are linked/navigated.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed by using `getKoin().loadModules(modules, true)`